# Is there a way to set application.conf location in Scala?

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

If i'm using Java, I can set custom `application.properties` location with something like this:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${APP_CONF_DIR}/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

Is there any way to do the same thing in Scala without using `"-Dbla.bla=app.config"` on application start

Comment: You load your config using typesafe config ? if so, you can point to whatever file you like when loading config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of Lightbend Config around loading `application.conf` is mostly from `ConfigFactory.load()`, which will look for `application.conf` or the file/resource given by Java properties (the `-Dconfig.file` and friends in your question).

If not interested in setting the alternative to `application.conf` through Java properties, one can load a different resource from the classpath with `ConfigFactory.load("foo")` to load `foo.conf`.  Alternatively if one is loading a file, one can use `ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseFile(file))`, where `file` is a `java.io.File`.